# Wordpress cp-appointment-calendar redirection to paypal issues

Tags: paypal, wordpress

I'm using cp-appointment-calendar for booking system on http://studioglamour.co.uk, but the problem is that when you enter date/time and information, you need to be redirected to paypal. I know that PayPal doesn't let ifames.

The question would be: how to do that when I press **continue** it would close the fancybox iframe, and redirect to PayPal in the main page?

Comment: Try `target="_top"` in the appropriate form / link

Comment: Yeah tried that, bus fancybox doesn't close. I know that the button to close fancybox has id="fancybox-close", but if I put this I into input field <input class="booking-cal-button" type="submit" name="subbtn" value="<?php _e("Continue"); ?>" /> it doesn't show at all.

Comment: so you have given your form `target="top"` and it still opens inside the fancybox? That's strange.

Comment: I need to open the form in fancybox, but after the submission of the form it should close fancybox and redirect to paypal.

Comment: Everything sorted out with target="_top". I have placed it in a wrong place before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use target="_top" in the appropriate form / link.

When used in a form, the form will submit into the whole window.

When used in a link, the link will open in the whole window.